# The ssh instead of ssh in /etc/init.d

Tags: ssh

I am reading the book `LPIC-1 Linux Professional Institue Certificate Guide` and encounter such a statement about sshd

> If you make changes to your SSH configuration, you may need to pass the reload or
>   restart option to the startup script, as in /etc/init.d/sshd reload. (Chapter 5 covers
>   startup scripts in more detail.) However it’s launched, the OpenSSH server binary name
>   is sshd.

However, I find `ssh` rather than a daemon `sshd` there

```
$ ls  /etc/init.d | grep ssh
ssh
```

What's the problem?

The machine details

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

Comment: That's probably systemd now, so `sudo systemctl restart ssh` should restart the ssh daemon. And according to [this site](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restart-ssh/amp/), it was `ssh` instead of `sshd` on Debian even before systemd.

Comment: thank you. could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @danzel

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh reload
service ssh reload
systemctl reload ssh
```

Please, note that in Ubuntu it is not *sshd*, but *ssh*.

Comment: Need `sudo` before all of them.

Comment: Of course. But, if you are in a desktop environment you will be prompted for your password.